# MongoDB service not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoid, systemd

I have recently upgraded my ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04. All features seems to be working fine except `MongoDB`. I am using mongoDB with ruby on rails application using Mongoid gem. MongoDB is not controllable from service as we do normally in ubuntu.

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

or

```
sudo service mongod start
```

I get this error message

> Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load:
>   No such file or directory.

But i have to start it manually each time i have to connect my application to MongoDB server using

```
sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

So `mongodb` is connected as long as that terminal is opened. I am using `MongoDB` in Ruby on Rails application using `Mongoid adapater/ORM`.

When i run

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

i get following output

```
mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since بدھ 2015-05-06 14:47:53 PKT; 5s ago
Docs: man:mongod(1)
Process: 28602 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=4)
Main PID: 28602 (code=exited, status=4)

مٓی 06 14:47:53 NX00443 systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
مٓی 06 14:47:53 NX00443 systemd[1]: Starting An object/document-oriented database...
مٓی 06 14:47:53 NX00443 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION
مٓی 06 14:47:53 NX00443 systemd[1]: Unit mongodb.service entered failed state.
مٓی 06 14:47:53 NX00443 systemd[1]: mongodb.service failed.
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to programming.

Comment: It is related to mongodb server installation issue on latest ubuntu version. MongoDB is database server can be used by modern programming languages. I am using it with ruby on rails 4. Its installation will help me application development.

Comment: How did you install Mongoid, if via apt did you try upgrading it did you try to debug the init scripts?

Comment: Yes i installed it via apt as documented in mongodb docs http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ Also i did updated it but it does't worked

Comment: Further i also uninstalled it and then installed it but it did't worked either

Comment: I have installed mongodb version 3

Comment: Have you checked the MongoDB logs to see if there are any errors when starting the service? If you're running `mongod` with `sudo`, I suspect you may have some file ownership issues in your data directory. The official [MongoDB installation on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) starts `mongod` (via the service definition) using the `mongodb` user account, not `root`. This also seems like a question better suited for DBA StackExchange since it is about database administration rather than programming.

Comment: There is nothing in log, when i try to start mongodb service i get this error Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Comment: IIRC, there is no package for 15.04 (yet). Furthermore, this *is* off topic, since SO is not about solving all problems that a programmer might run into, but programming questions. If you can't show affected code, there is a good chance you are off topic. Please post on http://dba.stackexchange.com next time (do NOT double post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above solution worked for me. There are few kernel level changes in ubuntu 15.04 and they are not going to resolve this issue in current release. Hopefully it will be fixed in next stable release of ubuntu.

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that `Mongo>2.6.3` has a known issue with start:

Support Systemd (cannot start mongodb with init scripts with Fedora 15 or above)

As noted here: [in this link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17742) and it seems that this possibly won't be fully fixed for `>2.6.3` until `Ubuntu 16.04`, unless there is a strong outcry.

So the **solution** is to issue:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb
```

This reverted back to `mongo 2.6.3` and NOW ALL WORKS! For those that run across this...

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the path configuration of the db:

for example in the file "/etc/mongod.conf" set "dbPath: /data/db"

You need to give the right to mongodb user to access this path:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb /data/db
```

Answer (score 3):

The above solution works for me too:

```
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb
```

I've tried several methods that I found in this site and other sites, but only this one works for me! So, for now, back to Mongodb 2.6.3!

**Update: problem fixed (2015/8/2 14:39):**
I just found out that MongoDB 3.0.5 is released, so I purged version 2.6.3 and tried to install 3.0.5 on my Ubuntu 15.04. But the problem remains! However, after I reintalled it with the Debian wheezy package instead, finally the `sudo service mongod start` command works (it didn't work when I install 3.0.4 debian wheezy version). Now the new MongoDB 3.0.5 is running fine on my Ubuntu 15.04!

To install Debian wheezy version, please refer to the official installation guide on MongoDB: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/

Comment: Your solution worked for me in Ubuntu 15.10 with mongoDB 3.0.7

Answer (score 3):

i saw `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` and it need to move authentication 2.6 schema to 3.0.5 schema and  i just removed journal and all DBs in `/var/lib/mongodb/` then restart the service and it worked again.

```
2016-01-17T14:43:08.529+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-01-17T14:43:08.529+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { command: [ "run" ], config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,10.0.0.170", http: { enabled: false }, port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongodb.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", quiet: true } }
2016-01-17T14:43:08.834+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Old 2.4 style user index identified. The authentication schema needs to be updated by running authSchemaUpgrade on a 2.6 server.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following commands helped me:

```
rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock 
mongodb restart
```

Answer (score -1):

It helped me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
cd /var/lib
sudo rm -rf ./mongodb
sudo mkdir mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb mongodb/
sudo service mongodb restart
```